# Enable zoom effect on jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I want to enable the standard zooming effect in jquery mobile on my iOS iphone jqm 1.3.2 app.

I already tried this:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

and

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
             $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
             $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'pop';

             $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage = 'Seitenladefehler';
             $.mobile.loadingMessage = 'Lädt...';
             $.mobile.dialog.prototype.options.closeBtnText = "Schließen";
             $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText = "Zurück";

             $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterPlaceholder = "Suchen...";

             $.mobile.activeBtnClass = 'unused';
             $.mobile.zoom.enabled = true;

             $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;

             //$.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;

         });
```

Still no two finger zooming inside the jqm app. what am I missing?

Comment: are you sure its not working? I just tested your code and its zooming.

Comment: no... the app was not supposed to be zoomed at the beginning, i'm not sure I cleared out all options that prevented zooming. are there any other possibilities to prevent zooming that I have missed maybe?

Comment: I meant zooming on two fingers movement. initial zoom is untouched.

Comment: yes two finger zooming is not working. are there any other zooming possibilities, except the native iOS zooming option under Settings>Accessebility? pretty wierd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not **remove** the **maximum-scale** all together:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes">
```

also on iOS, i believe **user-scalable** is set with a **1** instead of **yes** see the **[user-scalable spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/#user-scalable0)**

```
 <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=1">
```

or trying also without **user-scalable**

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

maybe also through the jQuery Mobile API:

```
$(document).bind( "mobileinit", function(event) {
       $.extend($.mobile.zoom, {locked:false,enabled:true});
});
```

**mobileinit** event:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/globalconfig.html

See Reference:

**[W3C CSS Device Adaptation Spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/#user-scalable0)**